# What is "<Esc>Kv" in bash

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

When I am in bash and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, bash fires up `$EDITOR` with a filename similar to `/tmp/bash-fc-186566385`.

Why is that and what is its purpose?

I probably need to mention that I am running bash with `set -o vi`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This allows you to construct a command with full Vi editing. If you type some commands in and save exit `:wq` the commands will be run.

CLARIFICATION: it allows you to construct the command in whatever editor you have set in `$EDITOR` and when you save and quit from it the contents will be run. (Clarified that it's not just Vi!)

ALSO, as noted by [RealSkeptic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/154971/realskeptic), the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> combination isn't required to bring up the editor. Simply <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> will.

Comment: Please note that few keyboards have a key labelled `v`. Pressing key (or better keys) to get `K` is normally marked up as `<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>` and pressing the key to get (lowercase) `v` as `<kbd>V</kbd>`

Comment: No but your edit to the OPs post did have incorrect ones.

Comment: Isn't the editor mode reachable simply by escape-V? The "shift-K" there seems to be just voodoo.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you are correct, good supplementary information

Comment: Also Ctrl-x + e (if you are not in vi mode)

Answer (score 12):

You don't need <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>. Using <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> will work since you are allowing shell command line editing using the built-in vi editor using `set -o vi` (same can be acheieved with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>). This is equivalent to execute the builtin `fc` command which is useful to manipulate the history list and history file. It will invoke whatever editor is set in your `$EDITOR` (otherwise, your shell's default editor) to write a long, tricky or complex command and then execute them after saving and closing the editor. See here for details about `fc` command: [Bash history builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html).